# Android custom image in status bar while audio is playing

Tags: android, audio, status, rom

I am trying to figure out a way to have a custom image display in the status bar of an Android device whenever audio is being played (independent of the app used to invoke the audio). I am not referring to an app or a notification, but rather I need this to happen on a system-wide level. From the research I've done I have found that this can not be done through the Android SDK and I will most likely have to create a custom ROM to do this. However I do not know if this is the correct solution and if it is, how would I get started? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the music icon in the notification is provided by the music app not the system...

One way of knowing this is try different music apps,  and check if u are getting same icon in notification...

If yes then you can easily change that icon, u need to be rooted of course...
Pull out framework-res.apk from /system/framework.
Extract it using 7-zip.
Go to folder /res/drawable-xxxx (where xxxx indicate your screen size like hdpi, mdpi, ldpi etc)
Then look for the icon that u saw in notification, renane your custom icon with the same name...
Replace it in 7-zip at that location with custom icon of same size, resolution n extension...